# Gridview not functioning when click event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

my grid view not working. when i click the sort on header it like not working . noting error and noting change. hopefully i can get explanation on my problem. No blame zone .just want get the solution here.
here below my code that i have been try but noting happen to my system.
[image: grid view]

[image: vb.net]

[image: Sorting]

hopefully i can get explanation.

Comment: try to post code directly instead of image. So, user can easily understand where is the problem and they can give u a proper solution. In this way u may get lot of down votes or close flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is due to concatenating the two string while applying sort in your code:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort=SortExpression & direction
```

Please try following sample:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="As Of Sales" SortExpression= "asofsales">
```

This will fix your problem to allow sorting,

```
Private Sub SortGridView(ByVal sortExpression As String, ByVal direction As String)

            If direction = "1" Then
                direction = "ASC"
            Else
                direction = "DESC"
            End If

            dt.DefaultView.Sort=SortExpression + " " + direction

            GridView1.DataSource = dt

            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Sub

    End Class
```

Before you were using 
            `dt.DefaultView.Sort=SortExpression & direction` ,  which would not work because it would concatenate, the two strings together and use them as a column name, which would cause the program not to find the column. So simply changed it to

```
    dt.DefaultView.Sort=SortExpression  + " " + direction
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not able to view the code properly in your image.

Please see:

- [GridView Column Sorting](http://forums.asp.net/t/1774411.aspx?Gridview%20help%20with%20sorting%20in%20VB)
- [GridView Sorting on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3)

**Update:**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

  Protected Sub TaskGridView_Sorting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewSortEventArgs)

    'Retrieve the table from the session object.
    Dim dt = TryCast(Session("TaskTable"), DataTable)

    If dt IsNot Nothing Then

      'Sort the data.
      dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression & " " & GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression)
      TaskGridView.DataSource = Session("TaskTable")
      TaskGridView.DataBind()

    End If

  End Sub


  Private Function GetSortDirection(ByVal column As String) As String

    ' By default, set the sort direction to ascending.
    Dim sortDirection = "ASC"

    ' Retrieve the last column that was sorted.
    Dim sortExpression = TryCast(ViewState("SortExpression"), String)

    If sortExpression IsNot Nothing Then
      ' Check if the same column is being sorted.
      ' Otherwise, the default value can be returned.
      If sortExpression = column Then
        Dim lastDirection = TryCast(ViewState("SortDirection"), String)
        If lastDirection IsNot Nothing _
          AndAlso lastDirection = "ASC" Then

          sortDirection = "DESC"

        End If
      End If
    End If

    ' Save new values in ViewState.
    ViewState("SortDirection") = sortDirection
    ViewState("SortExpression") = column

    Return sortDirection

  End Function

  Protected Sub Page_Load()

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

      ' Create a new table.
      Dim taskTable As New DataTable("TaskList")

      ' Create the columns.
      taskTable.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
      taskTable.Columns.Add("Description", GetType(String))

      'Add data to the new table.
      For i = 0 To 9
        Dim tableRow As DataRow = taskTable.NewRow()
        tableRow("Id") = i
        tableRow("Description") = "Task " & (10 - i)
        taskTable.Rows.Add(tableRow)
      Next i

      'Persist the table in the Session object.
      Session("TaskTable") = taskTable

      'Bind the GridView control to the data source.
      TaskGridView.DataSource = Session("TaskTable")
      TaskGridView.DataBind()
    End If

  End Sub

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Sorting example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

      <asp:GridView ID="TaskGridView" runat="server" 
        AllowSorting="true" 
        OnSorting="TaskGridView_Sorting" >
      </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```